# Access Control Permissions

Tags: network, network-access, access-control

I have created a topolgy in packet tracer displaying two networks. I have cpnfigured VLANs on both of the networks and configured access control lists. However, I would like to configure access control permissions based on read and write. I want both networks in the topology to be able to read one another information but deny access to make changes. In a nutshell, I would like network A to be able to read files or any other form of data stored on Network B and for Network B to deny change permissions so that Network A cannot alter any information on Network B. Could you please provide me with the right configuration to use. Thank you.[image]

Comment: When you say "read" and "make changes," what specifically do you mean? Do you mean files on the hosts?

Comment: in general. Files on host would be one of them but I am talking about data in general. I want one network to be able to read data on another network. This could be files, documents etc. But I don't want the network to make changes to it.

Comment: You need to be specific. For example, the network devices have ways of controlling what users can do on them, but that is very different than something like Microsoft CIFS control.

Comment: It sounds like you want a NextGen firewall to control what is allowed. You don't do that with routers.

Comment: And how would I do that? In other words, How do I configure this on packet tracer and where do I find this NextGen firewall on packet tracer?

Comment: You don't. Packet Tracer is pretty limited in what it can do.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Access control lists operate at layers 3 and 4 of the OSI or TCP/IP model.  File operations like reading and writing are application layer functions, so network ACLs have little or no control at that layer.

If you think about it, reading a file can be very different depending on the application.  Are you using FTP?  A word processing program?  A database application?  Each one has its own unique ways of reading a file.  At the network layer, these are all invisible to you.

Comment: I am not using any of the followings that you were questioning if I was using. It is just a basic network topology based on two individual networks connected as a whole via routers. All I did was doing basic switch and router configurations i.e. interface links on both switches and routers and configuring VLANs on switches as well as configuring ACLs on switches. But I would like to assign read and write permissions but unsure on what the configuration is to do that.

Comment: I think you’re missing an important concept. At the network layer, there is no such thing as read or write. Those are applications functions.  What are you writing to?